# OpenSpliceDDS with ssl configuration

Tags: data-distribution-service

I like to configure the OpenSpliceDDS as following.

I have to configure the centralized OpenSpliceDDS. It will send and  receive all data from global. In the centralized dds server only 443  port will be opened.

How to configure the OpenSpliceDDS with port 443 (secure layer) ??

Client machines have the local OpenSpliceDDS. the local OpenSpliceDDS  should be responsible sending local data to the centralized  OpenSpliceDDS with secure layer (443).

How to configure with client side ??

Thanks

Comment: What version of OpenSpliceDDS are you using?

Comment: OK, so that is the commercial version, not the Community Edition. As a heads up, I think that PrismTech's support will be able to give the best answer -- and you should have access to that since the commercial versions are available with support only. Is that correct?

Answer (score -2):

I'd be willing to wager that any DDS support for TLS will involve forfeiting many of the benefits of DDS.  The goals of TLS (or DTLS) and DDS seem nearly diametrically opposed.  TLS is designed to create a single communications channel which allows the peers to verify that the other is who they claim to be (though it's typically only in one direction).  DDS is designed such that the sender and receivers are completely decoupled and there's no notion of trust anywhere.

If there were, what would the semantic be?  If you're hoping you could create a QoS which decomposed TLS into its constituent features --  assert `DDS_ENCRYPTION_ENCRYPTED` but then use `DDS_AUTHENTICATION_NONE`?  ...well, those concepts are unfortunately inseparable.  It's meaningless to have a channel which is encrypted while the decryption endpoint is untrusted.

Longwinded story short: specifying the port doesn't grant you security and DDS is suboptimal for securing traffic.  Use TLS directly to secure the traffic that needs it, and DDS for everything else.

Comment: Actually there's a standardization effort for secure DDS communications. I don't believe that using TLS will forfeit any of the benefits of DDS. Of course, this is if implemented by taking into account the publish/subscribe nature and global data space of DDS. I believe the specification will address all the issues.

Comment: I'm sure it will address all the issues -- but without using TLS.